# Unable To Resolve Name In Lambda When Naming Nested Class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda, c++11

I'm using MSVC10.

I have a class `C` which is nested in class `B`, which in turn is nested in class `A`.  `B` has a member variable of type `C`, and `A` has a `vector` of `B`s.  Like so:

```
class A
{
  class B
  {
    string foo_;
    class C
    {
      string bar_;
    } c_;
  };
  vector<B> b_;
};
```

Within `A` I have a member function which uses `for_each` with a lambda, to iterate over the `vector<B>`.

In that lambda I try to get a reference to the `B` and the `C` (separately):

```
void A::Run()
{
    for_each(b_.begin(), b_.end(), [](std::vector<B>::value_type& that)
    {
        const B& b = that;
        cout << b.foo_;
        const B::C& c = b.c_;   //  'B' : is not a class or namespace name
        // const A::B::C& c = b.c_; <-- THIS COMPILES
        cout << c.bar_;
    });
}
```

The code: `const B::C& c = b.c_;` results in a compiler error, "'B' : is not a class or namespace name" *even though* the compiler had no problem accepting `const B& b = that;`

Is this syntax allowed by the language?

If I change it to:  `const A::B::C& c = b.c_;` the compiler accepts it.

Here is a complete example for you to play with:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void foo() {}

class A
{
public: 
    void Run();

    struct B
    {
        std::string foo_;
        struct C
        {
            std::string bar_;
        } c_;
    };

    std::vector<B> b_;
};

void A::Run()
{
    for_each(b_.begin(), b_.end(), [](std::vector<B>::value_type& that)
    {
        const B& b = that;
        cout << b.foo_;
        const B::C& c = b.c_;   //  'B' : is not a class or namespace name
        // const A::B::C& c = b.c_; <-- THIS COMPILES
        cout << c.bar_;
    });
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.Run();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is MSVC10.  I will update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the compiler. The code compiles fine with MSVC 2012 RC. I believe the pertinent bug is [this one](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/736295/incorrect-name-lookup-in-a-lambda-expression-defined-inside-a-class-member-function).

And the pertinent part of the standard is [expr.prim.lambda] 5.1.2 clause 7:

> The lambda-expression’s compound-statement yields the function-body
>   (8.4) of the function call operator, but **for purposes of name lookup**
>   (3.4), determining the type and value of this (9.3.2) and transforming
>   id-expressions referring to non-static class members into class member
>   access expressions using (*this) (9.3.1), **the compound-statement is
>   considered** in the context of the lambda-expression.

Comment: +1, I can't upvote answers with bug report links hard enough.